# Auto increment PK starting from zero - EF Core code-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core and EF Core with code-first approach. Database is SQL Server. Is it possible to increment `Id` primary key starting at 0?

Comment: Why do you want to start at 0 ?

Comment: @Shyju I have only 3 rows in particular table, and on the UI they need to have ID's 0,1,2 respectively. I know I can make another field of ID's and hardcore them for sake of UI, but I'm curious can I go without extra field.

Comment: Post your code and what are you expecting, because simple answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: I would recommend not using `identity` at all on this table. Just an ordinary `Id int primary key` which you will populate with your explicit values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it posible to increment Id primary key starting at 0?

Yes.  EF Core supports [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which you can start wherever you want.

EG:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("Order_seq", schema: "dbo")
            .StartsAt(0)
            .IncrementsBy(1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(o => o.OrderNo)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Order_seq");
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences

Comment: if I'm right, according to this all of my DbSets inside Context class will start with 0? What if I want just one DbSet (table) to start with 0?

Comment: Create different sequence objects for each Entity.

Answer (score 10):

With EF Core 3.x you can use [UseIdentityColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverpropertybuilderextensions.useidentitycolumn):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .UseIdentityColumn(seed: 0, increment: 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the table using T-SQL Script?

You can create an [IDENTITY (Property) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186775(v=sql.105)) column as follows:

**Syntax:**

```
IDENTITY [ (seed , increment ) ]
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE (
  ID_column INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

The `IDENTITY` property will auto-increment the column up from number 1. (Note that the data type of the column should be an integer.) If you want to add this to an existing column, use an ALTER TABLE command.