# I want to write entity to database with id = 0 but EF Core won't let me do it

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three tables represented by entities:

```
public class Verification
    {
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationEntry
    {
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }
        public VerificationGroup VerificationGroup { get; set; }
        public Verification Verification { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationGroup
    {
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Identifiers can have negative values and even 0 (conditions from the terms of reference, also the input of identifiers is user-defined).

When adding entities with identifiers not equal to 0 to the database using EF Core, everything is quietly added. If you use 0 as an identifier, then an exception is thrown. An example of an exception when trying to create a VerificationEntry between already existing Verification and VerificationGroup with id 0 and 3 respectively:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
"The value of 'VerificationEntry.VerificationId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. 
This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which 
the principal entity in the relationship is not known.
```

Suppose when adding a new entity with identifier 0, the following error occurs (there are a lot of logs, I think the informative part):

```
"Exception":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. 
See the inner exception for details.
\r\n ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 
23505: duplicate key value violates uniqueness constraint \"pk_verification_groups\"\r\n\r\n
DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. 
Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.\r\n
```

At the same time, manually adding such data to the database works fine. What can be wrong?

Also EF Core does not allow adding entities with an id = 0 to the database, but this can be done manually in the postgres database.

I tried to set the properties of the VerificationId and the VerificationGroupId as nullable values and it worked. But I cannot use this approach in the project.

Comment: this is probably more a question about entity Framework than about ASP.NET. 
ID 0 is a reserved number. It means not set, so to be assigned by the database. ID's by default should start with 1.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58171669/

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you, I understand this myself, but I was given a task where 0 and negative values can also be valid IDs. Everything works with negative values as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto increment PK starting from zero - EF Core code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012412/auto-increment-pk-starting-from-zero-ef-core-code-first). Defining a custom identity column will possibly help.

Comment: @JHBonarius сThanks, I looked at your links. In the first one, I understand that the author of the question refused to use id = 0. The second one uses a start value to automatically increase the id. I just need to save data that can have id = 0. That is, to have a record directly in the database with id = 0. The thing is, this is coordinated with another service and they may require one special entity to have id = 0.

Comment: OK, I think I jumped to early conclusions (and didn't read the full quesiton properly) sorry. I now see that the error is not thrown by Entity Framework specifically, but by the PostGres extension. That might be because it's actually thrown by the database itself. Duplicate key might mean there already is an entity with ID=0. However, like I said earlier: 0 is a reserved key value for EF, so It could also mean it's trying to use the auto-incremented identity value and thereby resuling in a key value that was already used.

Comment: ... Like the error message says, you can specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to see the details of the data send to the database. About the second link: it also configures the primary key AFAIK. Because that configuration is important. By the way, are you [telling EFCore that you want to manually set the ID value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/value-generation?tabs=data-annotations#inserting-explicit-values-into-identity-columns)?

Comment: I looked through some pages. Maybe it would help to change the default value property of the primary key property to something else than 0. [See this info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: If the input of identifiers is user-defined, then just make sure they are not auto generated, which is the EFC default for `int` type PKs. Either mark them with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` or use `ValueGeneratedNever()` fluent API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was helped by adding attributes to the model IDs that disable the database key creation mode. That is, the database will receive the ID that was sent by the service.

This is what my models look like now:

```
    public class Verification
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationEntry
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationId { get; set; }

        public VerificationGroup VerificationGroup { get; set; }

        public Verification Verification { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class VerificationGroup
    {
    
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int VerificationGroupId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```